# Android - How to reload a fragment on tab selection

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I developed an android application with action bar with 3 tabs and 3 frgments.I need the tabs to get a parameter from `SharedPreferences` and do some operations on it every time that a tab selected. The problem is that now the app do this operations just once at the start of application,  I do not know how to define this for every time that user select a tab, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Set an index for each tab when you add the tabs to the action bar like this

```
tabA.setTag(1); // 1 - for first tab
```

and Override the onTabSelected() method and do your operations for the fragment in the specific tab

```
 @Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    int tabIndex = (Integer)tab.getTag();
    // do your stuff here based not the tab id
}
```